# How can I set the user in phpunit config.xml

Tags: phpunit

Is it possible to set the user the test suite will run as when using phpunit. We have some tests that require you to run the suite as "www-data", and we'd like to be able to force that to happen in the config.xml so people don't need to remember to manually change their user when running it.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm having the same issue right now.